# Vba code to split cells based on parenthesis and spaces before and after parenthesis

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file that has some cells with several text in parenthesis and outside parenthesis. I would like to split the cells. For example , I have some cells appearing like this

`(some text in) parenthesis and (others outside)`

I would to split the cells so that the `some text in` is in a different cell, `parenthesis and` also in a different cell and `others outside` also in a different cell.  What I have so far only splits what's in parenthesis. Thanks in advance. Here's my code below

```
Sub StripCells()

Dim r As Range, i As Long
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "\(([^\)]+)\)"
    For Each r In Range("a1", Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        If .test(r.Value) Then
            For i = 0 To .Execute(r.Value).Count - 1
                r(, i + 2).Value = "'" & .Execute(r.Value)(i).submatches(0)
            Next
        End If
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you give some sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

If all your cells begin with an " **(** " then:

```
Sub fracture()
    Dim r As Range, a, arr, i As Long

    For Each r In Range("a1", Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        arr = Split(Replace(r.Value, "(", ")"), ")")
        i = 0
        For Each a In arr
            If i <> 0 Then
                r.Offset(0, i).Value = a
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Next a
    Next r
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a pattern that works.  (I cheat, and use `Replace()`, but it seems to do the trick):

```
Sub StripCells()

Dim r As Range, i As Long
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Global = True
    '.Pattern = "\(([^\)]+)\)"
    .Pattern = "((\(([^\)]+)\))|[\w+ ]+)"
    For Each r In Range("a1", Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        If .test(r.Value) Then
            For i = 0 To .Execute(r.Value).Count - 1
                r(, i + 2).Value = "'" & Replace(Replace(.Execute(r.Value)(i).submatches(0), ")", ""), "(", "")
            Next
        End If
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

[image]